# pass data to included ejs template

Tags: node.js, electron, ejs

In my `main.js` I have a code like this:

```
sendPostRequest('GET', 'user/get_accounts', {}, function (res) {
      res = JSON.parse(res);
      if (res.status === true) {
          var accounts = res.result.accounts;
          var currencies = res.result.currencies;

          showTemplate(APP.Templates.Account, {accounts: accounts, currencies: currencies, a: 'A'});
      }
}, true);

function showTemplate(template, data) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, APP.TemplatesPath, template),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }), data);
}
```

So I am passing my `ejs` template path but in my template I can not use the passed data.

Comment: What does this mean exactly: "but... I can not use the passed data"?

Comment: In my main.js I have object data which I need to pass to view (ejs tempalte)

Comment: I see, so you're passing the `data` into the second param of `loadURL`. Have you looked at the what the second param is for? It's for [options](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winloadurlurl-options), which is not how you're using it. Now I'm not sure what version of electron you're on, but 2.0 it looks like lets you pass an object that has an `UploadRawData`, which looks kind of like what you want.